# angular 2 child component not getting input data

Tags: angular, eventemitter

in my case i am trying to emit an event with data from one child of the parent to another child of the same parent. basically between siblings.

the code looks like

Child A

```
 @Output() makeIsrCall = new EventEmitter<LeadModel>()
 startCall(){
    this.makeIsrCall.emit(this.lead)
}
```

Parent 
.html

```
    <app-isr-call-toolbar *ngIf="core.isrCallInProgress == true" [data]="isrContact"></app-isr-call-toolbar>
 <app-edit-opty-workarea  [objId]="tb.id" [objType]="tb.objectType" (makeIsrCall)="makeCall($event)"></app-edit-opty-workarea>
```

.ts

```
 isrContact:any
 makeCall(lead:LeadModel){
    this.isrContact = lead
  }
```

Child B .ts

```
@Input() data:any
 constructor(private core:CoreStructureService) { 
    console.log('called construct for isr component')

    alert(this.data) //this comes undefined
  }
```

Comment: What is "Parent Child A"? Parent or child?

Comment: Please try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: sorry that is child

Comment: try to initialize isrContact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor is looong done before the data arrives

Either use `ngOnChanges` lifecycle callback

```
@Input() data:any

constructor(private core:CoreStructureService) { 
    console.log('called construct for isr component')
}

ngOnChanges() {
    alert(this.data) //this comes undefined
}
```

or make `data` a setter

```
@Input() set data(value:any) {
    this._data = value;
    alert(this._data) //this comes undefined
}

constructor(private core:CoreStructureService) { 
    console.log('called construct for isr component')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine, but instead of constructor try to get the value is ngOnInit or ngOnChanges.

e.g.

```
ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) {
    console.log( changes );
}
```

this works !!